# LSTM Sequence length

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to ask if there is an **optimal sequence length of a LSTM network** in **general**, or in terms of **time series prediction** problems?

I read about **vanishing gradient** or **exploding gradient** problems that very long RNN networks had and LSTM tried to solve and succeeded to a certain extent.

I also heard about techniques to handle very large sequences with LSTM’s and RNN’s in general like: truncating sequences, summarizing sequences, truncating backpropagation through time or even using an Encoder-Decoder architecture.

I asked this question because I didn’t find a **research paper** about this, only this [**blog post**](https://www.hardikp.com/2017/10/19/intraday-stock-price-prediction-2/#lstm-model) that stated an optimal **sequence length between 10-30**.

Comment: I'd say that the best approach is to do some model selection: Split your training set, train a few different lstms with a fixed amount of CPU time, and then take the one with the best predictive capability.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a hyperparameter which are "trainined" using a validation set? (like @Distjubo said)

Answer (score 1):

### Do some Model Selection.

**TLDR:** Just try it out.

Because training is already very computationally expensive, the easiest way to calculate how successful a model would be is to test it out. The combination that works best cannot be easily predetermined, especially not with such a vague description (or no description at all) of how the actual problem looks like.

From [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/159048):

> It totally depends on the nature of your data and the inner correlations, there is no rule of thumb. However, given that you have a large amount of data a 2-layer LSTM can model a large body of time series problems / benchmarks.

So in your case, you might want to try sequence lengths from 10 - 30. But I'd also try and evaluate how your training algorithm performs outside of that recommendation by the post you linked.